# How to convert data structure from integer to character in R?

Tags: r

I have imported data by read function

```
t_2020_10 <- read.csv("2020_10.csv")
```

and I want to convert 2 columns from integer to character. I've tried this:

```
t_2020_10$start_station_id <- as.character(t_2020_10$start_station_id)
```

However, it gave me this error message:

> Error in t_2020_10$start_station_id :
> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I'm sure the code is correct? could you please advise? and how can I convert data structure of multiple columns at once?

TIA

Comment: What is the output of `str(t_2020_10)`?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's hard to know what's going on otherwise

Comment: [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1412059)'s request is helpful for determining the source of the error. As for _"convert[ing the] data structure of multiple columns at once"_, the [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) package lets you do this with `t_2020_10 `[`%>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html)[`dplyr::mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html)`(start_station_id = as.character(start_station_id), another_column_name = as.character(another_column_name))`.